# Division of $ (X^2+1)^{6n+2}+X^4+1$ by $X^2+X+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The problem is like this : How do you find all the values of   $n\in \Bbb N $ for which the polynomial  $  (X^2+1)^{6n+2}+X^4+1$ divides the polynomial $X^2+X+1$?

Now, what I've tried is doing long division but it seems like that might not be the first step to start with. So I was looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $X^2+X+1$ is quadratic, it is easy to find its roots $\omega$ and $\omega'$. Now a polynomial $P$ is divisible by $X^2+X+1$ if and only if $P(\omega)=P(\omega')=0$.

To ease calculations, note that any root of $X^2+X+1$ is also a root of
$$(X-1)(X^2+X+1)=X^3-1.$$
Better yet, draw the roots in the complex plane to see that $\omega$ and $\omega'$ are roots of $(X^2+1)^6-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Working mod $x^2+x+1$, we have that $x^2+1\equiv -x$, and $x^3\equiv 1$ since $0\equiv(x-1)(x^2+x+1)\equiv x^3-1\pmod{x^2+x+1}$, so the polynomial becomes

$$\begin{align}(x^2+1)^{6n+2}+x^4+1&\equiv (-x)^{6n+2}+x(1)+1\\ 
&\equiv x^2(x^6)^n+x+1=x^2+x+1\\ 
&\equiv x^2(1)^n+x+1=x^2+x+1\\ 
&\equiv 0\pmod{x^2+x+1}.\end{align}$$

So, in fact, you are divisible for every $n$.